# How to add offset border to image of unknown size?

Tags: css, image, border

I'm trying to design this effect:

[image]

How do I make this work using css? The image size is unkown and I want the green box to be the same size as the image but offset?

I can't get any solution to work except sizing the green box using javascript but I think there must be a css solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo-class to do this :

```css
.imgContainer{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.imgContainer:before{
  content:'';
  border:1px solid green;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia18351-1041.jpg?itok=TyivXWrM">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like setting the outder div as display:inline-block was the piece I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with box-shadow if the images are placed on a solid color background. Set the first shadow with the same color as the background and the others with the color of the desired border.

```
img { box-shadow: 29px 29px 0 white,  31px 31px 0 green, 31px 27px 0 green, 27px 31px 0 green; }
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2dqzm45e/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you require a transparent background, you could create an image class that uses a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

```
.left-shadow,
.right-shadow {
    // Image rules
}

.left-shadow::before,
.right-shadow::before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.left-shadow::before {
    left: 20px;
}

.right-shadow::before {
    right: 20px;
}
```